# Making a GIF run when microphone is activated in processing

Tags: javascript, java, processing

Okay, so I'm making a project where I'm trying to run a gif file when the microphone is activated. To be more in-depth, I'm making a ditto transform cycle where the ditto transforms back to its normal state when it "hears" a noise, then goes back to normal. Every frame is going in a gif file so it will all be together in one file, the problem is that I am very new to code and am unable to figure out how to get this file anywhere past what I have now, which is the following;

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim       minim;
AudioInput  accessMic;
FFT         fft;
float boxSize;
PImage img;

void setup () {
  size(512, 500, P3D);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  img = loadImage("ditto.gif");
  accessMic = minim.getLineIn();
  rectMode(RADIUS);

}

void draw() {
  background(255,255,255);
  boxSize = (500);
  stroke(255);
  println(boxSize);
  fill(0);
  rect(width/2,height/2,boxSize,boxSize);
}
```

What I need is an in-depth explanation on how to get this functioning properly. When I run the file itself, all I get is a box, which is definitely starting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Break your problem down into smaller steps, and then try to accomplish those steps one at a time.

**Step 1:** Put together a program that just displays a rectangle. Don't worry about the microphone or the gif just yet.

**Step 2:** When you get that working, then create another separate program that only displays an animated gif. Don't worry about the microphone or minim yet. Processing comes with a ton of examples (go to File -> Examples) that can help you. [Here](https://www.processing.org/examples/loaddisplayimage.html) is an example on loading an image, and [here](https://www.processing.org/examples/sequential.html) and [here](https://www.processing.org/examples/animatedsprite.html) are more advanced examples on animation.

**Step 2.5:** After you get the gif displaying, then you can add functionality that only plays the gif after a simple event like a key press or a mouse click. You're still not worrying about the microphone yet! Try to go forward in small steps.

**Step 3:** When you get that working, create another completely separate program that just prints something to the console when the microphone detects something. Don't worry about drawing anything! Just focus on getting this one small piece to work.

**Step 3.5:** You've tagged this as a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) question. **Minim doesn't work in JavaScript mode.** If you're trying to deploy as JavaScript, you're going to have to use something else.

**Step 4:** Only when you have each of those smaller subtasks working completely separately, then you start thinking about combining them into one sketch. If you get stuck on a specific step, then you can ask a specific question and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! Ah yeah I figured I tagged it wrong :/ I know absolutely nothing about anything, but your advise really helped!